# Are there any tools that allow me to change all C# built-in types to their .NET Framework types?

Tags: c#

One of the things that I find hard to keep consistent is the use of `int` vs `Int32` and `bool` vs `Boolean` etcetera.

I find it simpler to identify all types by their case and color syntax highlighting...

```
List<int>
```

vs

```
List<Int32>
```

The latter is cleaner and upholds consistency. A lot of code is littered with both and I'm looking for a refactoring tool to change them all.

Are there any tools that allow me to change all C# built-in types to their .NET Framework types?

Comment: Personally, I prefer the former, but that's me :-)

Comment: This seems totally unnecessary. Are you bored? Or are you trying to enforce this on your colleges?

Comment: I understand being used to something you've become to familiar with, but having all types capitalized and colorized the same is a clear advantage to me.

Comment: I experienced that if you let ReSharper optimize your solution, that it changes `string` to `String` (which I personally hate, too). I'm not sure whether it changes `int` to `Int32`, too. On the other hand, some brave "Replace in Files" could be helpful, too.

Comment: The reason i prefer them is that the colorization shows it to be a built in primative.

Comment: Actually there is not difference between int or Int32 .. the int keyword is just a alias to make your code more readable.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare What advantage does that give?

Comment: [Roslyn may be a possibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh500769), using a custom `SyntaxRewriter`.

Comment: Seems like an editor problem to me. Go and find in options if primitive types use a certain color and change it to light-blue

Comment: a reason I wouldn't do this is, its not very idiomatic C#.  Especially if your only reason is the pretty colors :-)

Comment: The value of making these consistent is pretty low, IMO.

Comment: @NickStrupat: per my earlier comment, it IS possible with Roslyn. I've begun using it in some other projects and my answer below is a relatively decent approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually wrote a macro to do this

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module ReplaceCSharpBuiltInTypesWithTheirFrameworkTypes
    Sub ReplaceCSharpBuiltInTypesWithTheirFrameworkTypes()
        Dim dictionary As New Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
        dictionary.Add("bool", "Boolean")
        dictionary.Add("byte", "Byte")
        dictionary.Add("sbyte", "SByte")
        dictionary.Add("char", "Char")
        dictionary.Add("decimal", "Decimal")
        dictionary.Add("double", "Double")
        dictionary.Add("float", "Single")
        dictionary.Add("int", "Int32")
        dictionary.Add("uint", "UInt32")
        dictionary.Add("long", "Int64")
        dictionary.Add("ulong", "UInt64")
        dictionary.Add("object", "Object")
        dictionary.Add("short", "Int16")
        dictionary.Add("ushort", "UInt16")
        dictionary.Add("string", "String")
        For Each key In dictionary.Keys
            DTE.Find.FindWhat = key
            DTE.Find.ReplaceWith = dictionary(key)
            DTE.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocument
            DTE.Find.MatchCase = True
            DTE.Find.MatchWholeWord = True
            DTE.Find.MatchInHiddenText = False
            DTE.Find.PatternSyntax = vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxLiteral
            DTE.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResultsNone
            DTE.Find.Action = vsFindAction.vsFindActionReplaceAll
            DTE.Find.Execute()
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/), rule SA1121 actually enforces the opposite of what you want (asks you to change `Int32` to `int`).  It's fairly trivial to decompile that rule and create your own StyleCop rule to enforce the opposite.

This isn't automatic, but after you do your initial conversion, you can incorporate it into your builds and then flag any new uses as errors.

Comment: How would one go about decompiling the rule?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Roslyn CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh500769), the following appears to work in practice:

```
static SyntaxTree UpdatePredefinedTypes(this SyntaxTree tree)
{
    PredefinedTypeSyntax node;
    var root = tree.Root;
    while (null != (node = root.DescendentNodes()
                               .OfType<PredefinedTypeSyntax>()
                               .FirstOrDefault(
                                 syn => redefineMap.ContainsKey(syn.PlainName))))
    {
        var ident = Syntax.IdentifierName(redefineMap[node.PlainName]);
        root = root.ReplaceNode<SyntaxNode, SyntaxNode>(
            node, 
            ident.WithLeadingTrivia(node.GetLeadingTrivia())
                 .WithTrailingTrivia(node.GetTrailingTrivia()));
    }

    return SyntaxTree.Create(
        tree.FileName,
        (CompilationUnitSyntax)root,
        tree.Options);
}
```

When using a proper `redefineMap` (e.g. `{"int","Int32"}`, `{"double","Double"}`) the following program was converted successfully:

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int x = Int32.Parse("11");
            double y = x;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World! {0}", y);
        }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld {
    class Program {
        static void Main(String[] args) {
            Int32 x = Int32.Parse("11");
            Double y = x;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World! {0}", y);
        }
     }
}
```

When compiling:

```
var mscorlib = new AssemblyFileReference(
    typeof(object).Assembly.Location);

var newTree = UpdatePredefinedTypes(tree);

var compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                             .AddReferences(mscorlib)
                             .AddSyntaxTrees(new[] { newTree });
var results = compilation.Emit(File.Create("helloworld.exe"));
Console.WriteLine("Success: {0}", results.Success);
foreach (var message in results.Diagnostics)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", message);
}
// C:\tmp\cs>roslyn-test.exe
// Success: True
// 
// C:\tmp\cs>dir /b *.exe
// roslyn-test.exe
// helloworld.exe
//
// C:\tmp\cs>helloworld.exe
// Hello, World! 11
//
```

You can even utilize the `Workspace` features to update an entire solution:

```
var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(info.FullName);
var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
foreach (var project in solution.Projects
    .Where(prj => prj.LanguageServices.Language == "C#"))
{
    foreach (var doc in project.Documents
        .Where(d => d.SourceCodeKind == SourceCodeKind.Regular
                 && d.LanguageServices.Language == "C#"))
    {
        var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(
            doc.GetText(),
            doc.DisplayName);
        var newTree = UpdatePredefinedTypes(tree);

        solution = solution.UpdateDocument(doc.Id, newTree.Text);
    }
}

workspace.ApplyChanges(workspace.CurrentSolution, solution);
// when running this in VS on itself it correctly updates the project!
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any tools except the search and replace function of VS.

I usually use the c# alias for type declarations and the .NET type when I call static members

```
int i = Int32.Parse(s);
```

It is just a personal preference.

Comment: I've done that as well but quickly ran into problems with variable/method/field names that contain the type names, as well as cases like a method signature: `void Foo(string derp)`

Comment: It is a good idea to expand the find options and to check the "Match case" and "Match whole word" checkboxes.

Comment: Do you know exactly what "Match whole word" does? I've never figured that out.

Comment: If you are looking for `"String"` it will not find `"StringWriter"` for instance.